# Does node http.request use my computers configured proxy?

Tags: node.js, proxy, http-proxy

I have a proxy server configured in Internet Explorer, will node http request object make its outgoing connections from my proxy ip automatically? Or will it still use my non-proxy ip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will use the connection available to it, which is the OS's internet connection. Any proxy settings within Internet Explorer will only be applied to internet browsing within IE.

Comment: Oh I thought that the OS got it's connection settings from IE? I know that sounds weird, its just, other web browsers and I'm sure other applications seems to pick up IE's proxy settings don't they? Or am I completely wrong here.

Comment: Other browsers have import utilities that may or may not take the settings. I believe there is no built-in utility in windows for specifying an HTTP proxy, you will have to use 3rd party software.